# Why is Orleans not recognized in 'Orleans Grains Class Collection' project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, orleans

I'm trying to write a simple Orleans demo solution:

1. I've installed Orleans v1.0.0 via the [.msi from github](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/releases/tag/v1.0.1).
2. I've created a new Visual Studio 2013 solution.
3. I've created a new *Orleans Grains Interface Collection* type project.
4. I've created a new *Orleans Grains Class Collection* type project

In the **interface collection** project, I can type Orleans and VS2013 
Intellisense recognizes the namespace and its contents:

[image]

In the **class collection** project I can't:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: you have the `using Orleans` in the header did you also add it manually to the `references`

Comment: @MethodMan The reference to Orleans.dll exists in both projects. I did not add it manually. It was added by the project templates when the projects were created.

Comment: it was added to the header..but you should still make sure that it's added to the references.. or perhaps you should remove that reference and create a dependency folder and drop the dll there.. then point to it as well as adding the reference manually pointing to the new dependency folder.

Comment: When you say 'header' you mean the top of the file? Also, I've manually removed and re-added the reference to the same dll (C:\Microsoft Project Orleans SDK v1.0\SDK\Binaries\OrleansClient) in both projects, to no avail.

Comment: I mean in the .cs file in the `using` section

Comment: @MethodMan thanks. So yeah, I've tried your suggestions but still no resolution. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the project template type ('server' vs 'client').

Comment: Usually these sort of things happen when there's either a dependent assembly missing from references or a conflict of some kind. I haven't come across this sort of issue with Orleans, though. One thing you could try is to open ``References`` and double-click on ``Orleans`` to see if you can inspect the dll. I believe with the your current problem it shouldn't be possible and it could point you to explore new avenues.

Comment: @Veksi thanks. Oddly enough when I double click the reference, the object browser shows it just fine for both the "good" project and the "bad" one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to resolve my issue with generous help from Sergey Bikov from the Microsoft Orleans team.

What I did was:

1. I add the missing reference from my grain project to my interface project, and added `using MyGrainInterfaces1;` to *Grain1.cs*. (Just so my solution would build without errors)
2. I removed the references to the Orleans.dll from both my projects and then re-added them manually. (Path to Orleans.dll for me is *C:\Microsoft Project Orleans SDK v1.0\SDK\Binaries\OrleansClient\Orleans.dll*

Now the Orleans namespace is recognized in both projects correctly.

Side note: Not sure why this did not work for me when I tried it several days ago.

Comment: It seems to be the same as my answer. Could you please replay my solution? I've tried now both (unload/reload and remove/add reference), even VS restart, and all of the 3 works the same if you do them after a build. As @Veksi says, there seems to be some assembly reference issue, but I also can't figure out the root cause. If I delete all the bin/obj folders AND the .suo file after a build, IntelliSense continues to malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add reference from grain project to interface project, add `using MyGrainInterfaces1;` to Grain1.cs and build.
2. Unload/reload grain project. - This seems to be an IntelliSense "feature".

Comment: Thanks @laslzo-magyar. Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue for me. Any other ideas?